# My "puck" model object falls right through the "table" model in jMonkeyEngine

Tags: collision-detection, jmonkeyengine

So I am trying to learn jMonkey, I have understood everything so far, and I thought I understood how to make objects solid, so things can't go through each other. When I create my Collision shapes, I turn on the debugger which shows the shapes, and they appear correct. But when I run the code the puck falls right through the table and I have no idea why? I have been trying to learn from http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_collision.

```
public class Main extends SimpleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();

        AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
        settings.setResolution(1024,768);
        settings.setFrameRate(60);
        app.setSettings(settings);

        app.start();
    }

    private BulletAppState bulletAppState;

    private RigidBodyControl    table_phy;
    private RigidBodyControl    puck_phy;


    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {

        bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
        stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().enableDebug(assetManager);

        DirectionalLight sun = new DirectionalLight();
        sun.setDirection(new Vector3f(-0.1f, -0.7f, -1.0f).normalizeLocal());
        rootNode.addLight(sun); 

        cam.setLocation(new Vector3f(0.0f, -2.0f, 7.0f));

        initTable();
        initPuck();
        initPusher1();
        initPusher2(); 

    }

  //My hockey table   
    public void initTable() {
        Spatial table = (Node)assetManager.loadModel("Models/airTable/airTable.j3o");
        table.setLocalTranslation(0.0f, -5.0f, -2.0f);
        CollisionShape tableShape = CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape((Node) table);
        table_phy = new RigidBodyControl(tableShape,0.0f);
        table.addControl(table_phy);
        rootNode.attachChild(table);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(table_phy);
    }

    //My puck 
     public void initPuck(){
        Spatial puck = assetManager.loadModel("Models/puck/puck.j3o");
        puck.setLocalTranslation(1.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f);
        CollisionShape puckShape = CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape((Node) puck);
        puck_phy = new RigidBodyControl(puckShape, 0.05f);
        puck.addControl(puck_phy);
        rootNode.attachChild(puck);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(puck_phy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From testing you code with my own models the only thing I can think of is your puck is clipping with the table on load.